# SwiftUI, 2 Texts from a speechToText model in 2 views, only one of them is showing the transcription, why?

Tags: speech-to-text

I've have the following SwiftUI-code, which should transcribe and create two texts from the file: SpeechRecognizer.swift. I'm using the Apple tutorial: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/app-dev-training/transcribing-speech-to-text

```
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  speechToTextTest_2
//
//  Created by Thomas Huelsmann on 9.1.24.
//

import SwiftUI

//MARK: - Main View: Contentview with Record-Stop-Button

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var speechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer()
    @State private var isRecording = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            
//MARK: - Headline
            Text("Two Texts: A, B")
                .frame(width: 250, height: 30)
                .font(.custom("Avenir Next Medium",fixedSize: 30))
                .padding()
            
//MARK: - Record-Stop-Button
            Button(action: {
                if !isRecording {
                    speechRecognizer.startTranscribing()
                } else {
                    speechRecognizer.stopTranscribing()
                }
                
                isRecording.toggle()
            }) {
                Text(isRecording ? "Stop" : "Record")
                    .font(.title)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding()
                    .background(isRecording ? Color.red : Color.blue)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .padding(10)
            }
            
//MARK: - Text A, working
            VStack (alignment: .leading){
                Text("Text A, which is working:\n\(speechRecognizer.transcript)")
                    .padding(10)
            }
            VStack (alignment: .leading){
                SecondText() // Text, which does not work
            }
        }
    }
}

//MARK: - Second View, separate View, Text B, not working

struct SecondText: View {
    @StateObject var speechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer()
    var body: some View {
        VStack (alignment: .leading){
            Text("Text B, which does not work:\n\(speechRecognizer.transcript)")
        }
    }
}

//MARK: - Preview

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

Does anybody is seeing or knowing the reason, why only Text A is showing the transcribed text from SpeechRecognizer model.

Thanks for any help, hint or idea, where to look for an explanation.

Best

Thomas

I tried the above code and expected my spoken voice been shown up twice. I see my spoken text only once.